# Allow remote access to a localhost website in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, localhost, port, lan

Hi I have developed a website and is on a machine(localhost),  I want a friend to access it from outside my network, I have done some research and am being pointed to port forwarding as a solution. Any good links I can refer too will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Not a programming question, but how to setup your router.

The router, especial the adsl modems that you probably use, they not forward outside request to inside network, for security and because they are not know where to send them.

So on the setup of your router you need first of all forwarder the outside calls to your pc.

Now, this have two parameters, what **port** send to what **inside ip**.

[How to forward ports on your router](http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/) page with images and examples.

Let say that you have a pc behind the router at ip 192.168.1.100, and setup there a local iis on 80, then you need to setup the router so when is accept call on port 80, to send it to 192.168.1.100

Now you need to know what ip to give to your friend to try to make call to you,  you can find it using the http://www.whatismyip.com/  The ip they see you outside is the one your friend must type on browser.

And then need to make your iis run, and allow your pc firewall to accept calls on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

@Aristos gave you the answer. But have in mind that some internet providers block port 80 so you might have to change to 88 for example. And your friend will access it as

```
http://your_external_ip:88
```